# tensorflow: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'use_synthetic_data' when following official ResNet setup

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have dowloaded and followed the step from the official tensorflow GitHub (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official) to run a ResNet model on cifar10, i.e. added the path as explained and successfully run the command line:

```
$ python cifar10_download_and_extract.py
```

But when running the command line

```
$ python cifar10_main.py
```

I got the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "cifar10_main.py", line 253, in <module>
absl_app.run(main)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 274, in run
_run_main(main, argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 238, in _run_main
sys.exit(main(argv))
File "cifar10_main.py", line 242, in main
input_function = (flags_obj.use_synthetic_data and get_synth_input_fn()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'use_synthetic_data'
```

Being not familiar with flags object used here by tensorflow, I am not sure where to look for resolving this list attribute

Comment: Same problem here...